# How to create a list from the name of a String in Java?

Tags: java

This is just a portion of of my project that I hit a road block on, but basically what I am facing right now is this. I have a text file full of commands that I read individually line by line into a an array I named tokens[]. tokens[0] has the command it is calling, while token[1] or anything else is a name or anything that is used with the method. In this case token[0] is a addlist method that it invokes, and token[1] is the name of the list. What is the best way to create a list of strings with name from token[1]. This method could be called multiple times in which it needs to create another list if it doesn't exist already. What type of structure should I use for this, and how could I go about this? Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: where is  your code? Post your code along with a sample of your text file.

Comment: Loop over the array and add them to a List<String> of strings.

Comment: Sorry, but I think you misunderstood what I was going for. Basically all I need to figure out is a way to take token[1] (which is suppose to be the name of the list) and create some sort of list out of it. Obviously I can't just do ArrayList<String> token[1] = new ArrayList<String>(); , but I need a way that will get me that result. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What if I did a 2D arraylist that holds the names of the lists, then add the names to the arraylist under the name of that arraylist? Would that work?